# How to resolve problem with adding blobs into array by getting them from the promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, url, blob

I have an array of image paths, and I need to convert it to array of blobs:

I use a function:

```
const pathToBlob = async (url: string) => {
    return await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob())
        .then(blobFile => new File([blobFile],
            "fileNameGoesHere", {type: "image/png"})
        )
}
```

Then I'm trying to use it:

```
let blobs:any = []

if (vehicle.images) {
    for (let i of vehicle.images) {
        //@ts-ignore (cant type i into loop)
        const file = pathToBlob(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+i.img)
        blobs=[blobs,...file] // error
        console.log(file) //    [[Prototype]]: Promise [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled [[PromiseResult]]: File
    }
    console.log(blobs)
}
```

But I'm recieving a Promise with:

```
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: File
```

Otherwise Into function (if I refactor to `const file = await....` `console.log(file)`)
I'm getting a ready blob.

Comment: `pathToBlob` is still async, you need to await it.

Comment: @Axekan if i refactor to `const file = await pathToBlob(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+i.img)` it returns me  `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.`

Comment: I posted an answer that I think could solve it, could you try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I added an async `iife` to get an async context since I don't from where you are running this. This is needed to be able to use `await`.

```js
const pathToBlob = async (url: string) => {
    const blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
    return new File([blob], "fileNameGoesHere", { type: "image/png" });
}

(async () => {
    const blobs: Array<File> = await Promise.all(
        vehicle.images.map(async (image: any) => {
            return pathToBlob(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+image.img);
        }),
    );

    console.log({ blobs }); 
})();
```